# Looking for regexp to keep some strings

Tags: regex, string, sed

This is the string I'm trying to regexp :

> 15C (59F) ambient, 22C (71F), 20C (68F), 26C (78F), 21C (69F), 27C (80F), 30C (86F), 33C (91F)

Actually I would like to keep only temperatures values in degrees without the C letter and to delete the other strings.

Can someone help me to do so ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Try [`(\d+)C\s\(\d+F\)[^,]*` and replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/xcumne/1).

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Thank you. I use sed. I tried the solution given by Wiktor but it did not work, can you give me the complete line including Sed ? Thanks.

Comment: To tag a user you must use the `@`. I haven't used `sed` but since it is POSIX I think you'll need to swap the `\d`s to `[0-9]` and `\s` to a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=C)' file
```

Output:

```
15
22
20
26
21
27
30
33
```

Comment: Thank you Cyrus it's working well. But do you have another solution using the sed command?

Comment: With GNU sed and result in one line: `sed 's/C ([0-9]\+F)[^,]*,*//g' file`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!